# Php - date - between

Tags: php, sql

I use

$date = date("Y-m-d");

and in sql i use between max is = date("Y-m-d") min is = 6 days back

Is there a function that gives from date back $limit?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand exactly what you want

Comment: i have date("Y-m-d") = 2012-04-12 what i want is that also 2012-04-05 is there a function that give me 6 days ago

Comment: I think that what Dan is suggesting is that you edit your question to make it more clear.  For example, use an example.

Comment: Yeah try to improve the question, although I think I understood it now. But SO serves as library where everyone can look up questions/answers.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, it could be done like this:

```
$date_first    = date("Y-m-d"); //today's date or use some other date
$date_second = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_first)) . " -6 day")); //date before 6 days
```

**EDIT**

Based on Dan Lee's suggestion(see the comment below):

```
$date_before = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-6 day"));
```

Comment: `strtotime('-6 days')` is enough, but you would need to cover it with `date()`

Comment: @Dan Lee: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added that solution also(credit goes to you) :)

Comment: @Mert Metin: yeah sorry for that. I forgot to wrap it in a `date()` to  display a formatted date, instead of the timestamp. What you are getting is the timestamp. So, just pass it to the `date()` function along with the date format "Y-m-d".

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL only for this task.

Take DATE_SUB() to subtract from the current time:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the OO variation of @AkhileshBChandran's answer:

```
$dt = new DateTime('-6 days');
$sixDaysAgo = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```